# Usar Múltiple Login Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

estoy tratando de usar el componente auth dentro de un controlador en donde realizo un login distinto al que uso para todo el proyecto para lo cual leí en la documentación que se puede usar este método

**$this->Auth->config()**

Bien lo implemente de la siguiente manera

```
class PersonasController extends AppController{

    //Aqui inicializo el componente y configuro el mismo
     public function initialize() {
    parent::initialize();
    $this->Auth->config([
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'userModel' => 'Personas',
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'usuario',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Personas',
            'action' => 'login'
        ],
        'authError' => 'Ingrese sus Datos',
        'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Evaluaciones',
            'action' => 'evaluation'
        ]
    ]);
  }
   //Aqui mi funcion login la cual se encarga de validar los datos que se    envian desde el formulario

   public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user_person = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user_person) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user_person);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }  else {
            $this->Flash->error('Usuario y/o clave errado',['key' => 'authperson']);
        }
    }
    $this->viewBuilder()->layout('public');
   }
}
```

Cuando realizo las pruebas muestra el mensaje de error
**Usuario y/o clave errado**
No se si falte algo o tengo que cambiar dentro de la función ayuda por favor Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi solución fue esta

```
public function initialize() {
    parent::initialize();
    $this->Auth->config([
        'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Personas',
            'action' => 'login'
        ],
        'authenticate' => [
            'Basic' => ['UserModel' => 'Personas'],
            'Form' => [
                'userModel' => 'Personas',
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'usuario',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'authError' => 'Inice Sesión',
        'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Evaluaciones',
            'action' => 'evaluation'
        ],
    ]);
}
```

y por otro lado hubo otro error en mi función para el registro de usuarios con las contraseña, corregí eso y funciono :)